# How do you initialize a struct with default values in typed/racket?

Tags: struct, macros, scheme, racket, typed-racket

I'm writing my first typed/racket application which is a cli application which asks you some statistical questions about your day such as how many hours you have slept the previous night, how much you have eaten, how many cups of coffee you had etc. The application does this by first displaying the question and then waiting for user input via the function `read`. The gathered information is then put into a `struct` with predefined fields.

The `struct` looks like this:

```
(struct: day-stats 
    ([user-id : Integer]
     ;; ... 10 more Integer fields
     ))
```

My approach for this is to first initialize the struct with a default value of 0 for each field and then updating that "instance" of the struct with information as the user inputs it, using the `struct-copy` function.

That leads me to the question, how do I initialize struct with default values in the most elegant way? Do I create a macro which creates code during compilation/parsing which looks something like this:

```
(day-stats 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
```

Or is there already a macro which can do this by reading some kind of property in the struct?

**EDIT:**

After consulting the documentation some more I found out that there are a property you can set in a struct to auto set fields. **However I can't find if this is possible in `typed/racket`.** Here's what it looks like in `racket`:

```
(struct day-stats 
    ([user-id #:auto]
     ;; ... 10 more Integer fields
    )
    #:auto-value 0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Structs that use `#:auto` aren't supported in Typed Racket currently.  In general, `#:auto` is a pretty inflexible feature, which I wouldn't use normally, either in Racket or in Typed Racket.

Instead, just create a simple constructor function, like this:

```
#lang typed/racket
(struct: day-stats ([x : Integer] [y : Integer]))

(define (mk-day-stats) (day-stats 0 0))

(mk-day-stats)
```

This generalizes easily to lots more fields.  You can hide the regular constructor by controlling what you `provide` from your module.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! On a side note, do you recommend to keep using `typed/racket` for a beginner or should I familiarize myself with `racket` first?

Comment: Well, as its author, I'm somewhat biased in favor of Typed Racket.  :)  But you ought to be able to learn just fine in Typed Racket, although most of the introductory material is written for plain Racket, and you'll have to translate it yourself.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again, and keep up the brilliant work with Typed Racket! :)